# Enable / Disable IMAP / POP Access on all Zoho email accounts

Tags: email, imap, zoho

Within Zoho Email, IMAP Access is disabled by default. I can enable this for each account individually, but I'd like to enable it for all accounts instead of selecting them one-by-one. How can I do this?

[image: Zoho Email - User Details]

I may also want to disable POP Access for all accounts at once, or enable ActiveSync Access. Over a few dozen email addresses this gets really tedious without a bulk update feature.

Answer (score 2):

You change the default settings only if you're a super admin.

Steps:

1. Login to mail.zoho.com as Super Admin.
2. Go to Control panel
3. User Details
4. Click on the email address
5. And you can modify the IMAP and POP setting for all the users in the organization.

Hope this helps.